# Need a formula to calculate (i->0 to n-1 )π(n!/i!)

Tags: c, math

I need a formula to calculate the expression multiplication of (n!/i!) where i varies from 0 to n-1. So that I can implement it to a Code. trivial way exceed time limit.Any quick suggestions are welcome

Comment: Did you try a for loop from 0 to n-1 and make the multiplication in the body?

Comment: You should ask your question at http://math.stackexchange.com/, then write code about it.  If the code does not work, then ask it here.

Comment: The result would be huge (too big to fit in any standard type) for almost all `n`.

Comment: If F(n) is your function, a little algebra shows that F(n+1) = pow( n+1, n+1) * F(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = (n!/i!) = (i+1) * (i+2) * ... * (n)
```

So, in pseudo-code (doing it in reverse order for increased efficiency):

```
x = 1;
result = 1;
for (j = n; j > 0; j--) {
  x = x * j;
  result = result * x; // Or + if you want the sum instead of the product
}
return result;
```

Note that you may need a bigint representation for `x` and `result` as they will overflow quickly.